# How to I convert PCM 24 bit wav files to mp3 using c#?

Tags: mp3, wav, naudio, lame

How to I convert PCM 24 bit wav files to mp3 using c#?

I know the [nAudio.Lame](https://github.com/Corey-M/NAudio.Lame/blob/master/MP3FileWriter.cs) library offers conversion functionality. But it looks like it doesn't support wavs in this format:

This is a code snippet from nAudio.Lame

```
if (format.Encoding == WaveFormatEncoding.Pcm && format.BitsPerSample != 16)
                throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("Unsupported PCM sample size {0}", format.BitsPerSample), "format");
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know where you found that code snippet, but it's not in the NAudio codebase. Also, if you need to convert 24 bit audio to another bit depth in NAudio, start with the `Pcm24BitToSampleProvider` class, which gets you to IEEE float. Then you can go back to 16 bit if you need, but most MP3 encoders will accept floating point input.

Comment: Its from NAudio.Lame, I edited the link title to make it clearer. Thanks for you advice, ill give it a try.